# Can a FAILWITH error be caused by improper gas_limit or storage_limit?

Tags: smart-contracts, gas

Sanity check question: Can a FAILWITH error be caused by improper (too low) values of gas_limit or storage_limit?
I'm guessing the answer is "no", but I'm debugging and stranger things have certainly happened.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is no. gas_limit and storage_limit are validated by separated filters.

Comment: Thanks! If you turn this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that can trigger a FAILWITH error is the execution of the FAILWITH instruction. You might however get a gas exhaustion error during the interpretation of a FAILWITH instruction, this can happen for example if the value that is thrown by FAILWITH is large because it will be costly to serialize.